# How do I get text and a progress bar on the same line?

Tags: progress-bar, progress

I need a way around using the div tag on the progress bar because I want the text to be inline with the progress bar. I am using jQuery to create a table and I can't figure out how to not use the div tag. I want the text outside the progress bar and inline with it.

I have tried the progress tag, but I can't get it to take my values that I want to implement. For the progress tag, I tried $(.progress).width(50%) which worked for the progress-bar class and I tried $(.progress).val(50). Therefore, this tag won't work compared to the progress and progress-bar class.

"td>" + 2 + "div class='progress'>" +
 "div class= 'progress-bar'aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'>" + "/div >" +"/div >" + 6 + "/td>"

Comment: Have you tried using <span>?

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work. Thank you, though